# How do you use the word "ĵus"?

Tags: word-usage

The word *ĵus* in Esperanto means "just", but is it used in the same way as it is in English? In English, you can say; *I just want some pizza*, where *just* has the same meaning as *only*. However, you can also say *He just arrived* which refers to the time when he arrived. Can the Esperanto word also be used like this, or not like this at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Vortaro:

**ĵus** 
*Cirkonstanca morfemo, signifanta "momenton antaŭ nun" aŭ "antaŭ tiam.* 
A circumstantial morpheme, meaning "a moment before now" or "before that time".

**Examples**:

- The sixth hour just struck. 
   
  *ĵus batis la sesa horo*
- I just talked about that. 
   *ĝuste pri tio mi ja ĵus parolis*
- I just spoke with the boss. 
   mi ĵus parolis kun la mastrino

With regards to "I just want some pizza", the word you are looking for is (among other definitions):

**nur** 
Partikulo uzata antaŭ subst. sen determinanto kvanta, por signifi "neniu", "nenio alia ol". 
A particle used before a noun without a quantitative determinant to mean "no one", "nothing other than".

**Examples**:

- Left foolish, returned only older. 
   *forveturis malsaĝa, revenis nur pli aĝa*
- You only need to follow me. 
   *vi bezonas nur sekvi min*
- I want to walk only with you. 
   *mi deziras promeni nur kun vi*

Comment: I personally prefer "simple" instead of "nur" but that works too.

Comment: @ClaytonRamsey Nothing wrong with that but when I imagine myself sitting on my couch, craving some pizza, I just see myself saying, "Ve, mi nur volas (mangxi) picon!" :P

Comment: @Ella And another translation of English "just" is "*justa*" which means "just" like a just judge, in the sense of "fair". And then there's "*ĝuste*", which means "just" in the sense of "exactly", as in "I mean just that!" As you can see, "just" is a very broad word!

Comment: @ClaytonRamsey I tend to use "simple" for this, too.

Answer (score 14):

*Ĵus* applies to time. For your example, it would be "Li ĵus alvenis." However, *ĵus* does not apply to "merely." For the other example, you should say, "Mi simple deziras iom da pico."